# How to generate a dynamic column

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js, twitter-bootstrap-3

Ok, say I have this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
</div>
```

That's two columns so far.

Now, say the layout is supposed to change dynamically to three columns, like this maybe:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>
```

How do I insert the third column dynamically?

My javascript is non-exist, my jquery barely passing. But nonetheless, if the *javascript solution* is required here, let me know.

Background info: This is in a ROR application that's using Backbone.js.

**EDIT**

For further clarification.

So, say that the columns are unequal, and when you add another column dynamically, how do you adjust the other columns to reflect the additional column?

Comment: And what would be the trigger to append third column? a button click ?

Comment: @PedroLobito, probably ... does it matter? Honestly, I'm not sure yet.

Comment: I've posted a working example below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, it looks like you're using a predetermined grid system. Those are usually twelve across. What that means is that  you can only have 12 grids at any time. So instead of the two columns that look like this:

```
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
    <div class="col-xs-6">.col-xs-6</div>
    </div>
```

Because half of 12 is 6 each. That means that to have three columns it would look like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-4">.col-xs-4</div>
</div>
```

Because 12 divided by 3 is 4 each. To create the 3 columns from the 2 columns you could use javaScript or jQuery. jQuery looks like this:

```
$(".row").empty().append("<div class='col-xs-4'>.col-xs-4</div>
  <div class='col-xs-4'>.col-xs-4</div>
<div class='col-xs-4'>.col-xs-4</div>");
```

Keep in mind there are several ways to perform this action. I think this is probably the easiest to comprehend!

Comment: I am. Twitter Bootstrap to be specific. And this would adjust the layout accordingly? I.e., I don't have to worry about how the overall display get topsy-curvy with the new column?

Comment: I'd have to see more of the script to be certain, but what this does is empties out anything with the class "row" and replaces it with the appended elements. If you want it to be more specific to that row I'd give the div with the class="row" an id so you can more easily reference it.

Answer (score 0):

To create an element and insert it into the document object model (DOM) you would traditionally take the following appproach:

```
// create your element
var newDiv = document.createElement("div");

// set element properties
newDiv.className = "col-xs-6 col-md-4";
newDiv.innerHTML = ".col-xs-6 .col-md-4";

//select your parent element
var parentDiv = document.querySelector(".row");

//append your new element to the parent element
parentDiv.appendChild(newDiv);
```

In your case, I suspect selecting the parent element will be the trickiest part. Check out the CSS selectors references [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started/Selectors) and [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors). Use a CSS selector as a parameter to `document.querySelector()` to grab the parent element.

You can also use `element.insertAdjacentHTML()` to insert HTML as a string like so:

```
//select your parent element
var parentDiv = document.querySelector(".row");

//insert adjacent HTML as a string
parentDiv.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",
    "<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-4'>.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>");
```

Finally, you can manipulate the element's HTML directly:

```
var parentDiv = document.querySelector(".row");
parentDiv.innerHTML += "<div class='col-xs-6 col-md-4'>.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>";
```

While that last option may seem like the quickest to write, it's the most performance intensive. `insertAdjacentHTML` is extremely efficient, but you don't always want to deal with HTML elements as strings, so it's often better to use `document.createElement` and `element.appendChild`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the jQuery [click](https://api.jquery.com/click/) and [append](https://api.jquery.com/append/) methods . So, whenever a button (`id="appendTo"`) is clicked, a new div will be appended to `<div class="row">`, i.e.:

```js
var divNum = 3; 
$("#appendTo").click(function(){  
   divNum ++;
   $(".row").append('<div id="myId'+divNum+'" class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">New Div '+divNum+'</div>');                
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
  <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">.col-xs-6 .col-md-4</div>
</div>

<button id="appendTo"> Click to Append</button>
```